# How to simulate 2 timestamp fields in a MySQL table?

Tags: php, mysql

I know you can only have 1 timestamp per table in mysql. But I need 2. One for when an article was created and one for everytime it's updated. The latter is the one that will be changing most of the time so I decided to make that the timestamp field. For the other one, how can I prepare the time in PHP so that it looks just like a timestamp when inserted into the database:

```
2011-07-29 03:28:20
```

And if this string is prepared in PHP, will the usual ways of formatting it work, e.g.:

```
    $time = strtotime($timestamp);
    $date = date('n/d/Y @ g:i a', $time);
```

Comment: Wait, who said you can have only one timestamp column?

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to involve PHP in this.  You can use the following pattern defaulting to NULL on the creation timestamp column, and using an `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` for the updated column.

```
CREATE TABLE test.table (
  `row_inserted` TIMESTAMP NULL,
  `row_updated` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)
```

This is copied from an example on the [MySQL TIMESTAMP docs.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a datetime field in order to store insert time (use now() function of mysql).
Use instead a timestamp field to store update time.

```
create table mytb (
id int not null auto_increment primary key,
article varchar(50),
ins_time datetime,
upd_time timestamp not null default current_timestamp on update current_timestamp
) engine = myisam;

insert into mytb (
article,ins_time) values ('bla bla bla', now());

update mytb set article = 'bla bla' where id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use MySQL function `NOW()` in your `INSERT` and `UPDATE` queries.

```
UPDATE table SET modified = NOW() WHERE id='$id'
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options: inside SQL using `NOW()`:

```
sprintf("UPDATE table SET modified = NOW() WHERE id=%d", $id);
```

Or using a timestamp created in PHP:

```
$now = time();
sprintf("UPDATE table SET modified =%d WHERE id=%d", $now, $id);
```

The first is ideal if you only have one roundtrip to the database: insert all data at once. 
The second allows you to carry the `$now` variable around for some time and re-use it. For example if you are inserting several records in a loop: you know for sure that they all have the same timestamp. Another advantage of the latter, is that time-difference between the database-server and PHP do not matter.

NOTE: I used sprintf for a minimum of security against SQL-injection. This is not, however, real and solid security. You will have to deal with cleaning data yourself trough a proper database layer.